# AWS CloudFormation: Stacks need to reference one another

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Dear Stackoverflow Users,

I work on an application that consists of multiple stacks, where each stack represents one microservice. According to architecture, one resource in stack 1 must be referenced in stack 2, and one resource in stack 2 must be referenced in stack 1. Below you find a visual representation of the idea:
[image]

As far as I understand, [CloudFormation ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) won't work here, as two stacks need one another to be created. Do you have any idea on how to implement this architecture? Thank you.

Kind Regards

Oleksii

Comment: You need to split it into tree stacks to break this circular dependency.

Comment: Advice here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/handling-circular-dependency-errors-in-aws-cloudformation/. You should include information on what the circular dependencies are because that can matter when it comes to resolving the problem.